# Help with MetaMask

Tags: metamask, bsc

Hope you're well today. Was wondering if you're able to explain me how to add on my website a feature that they click on the bottom “connect MetaMask” then connects to people's wallet and shows them their BSC coin and its balance according to BscScan. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be used if you have ethers.js active:

```
let accounts = await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
let account = accounts[0];
```

You can do this with MetaMask browsers, no ethers:

```
const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
const account = accounts[0];
```

`account` will be their address.
Now, with Web3.js, here's how to get their balance:

```
const balance = web3.eth.getBalance(account)
```

`balance` will be their balance.